# i am trying to compile sass and js with laravel mix and web pack

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

I am trying to compile sass and javascript with laravel mix and webpack but my js does not get compile even though I give me a success message.

Here is my webpack.mix.js  code...

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath('public');
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/main.css');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/main.js');
```

and here is my app.js code ....

```
window.$ = window.JQuery = require('jquery');

window.Vue = require = 'vue';

require('foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min');
require('slick-carousel/slick/slick.min');

// custom js
require('../js/init');
```

and in the only scenario, it get compile is if I remove the vue.js from app.js
so clearly there is some wrong with that line anyone know what it is
and here is the error I get in the console log

```
Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at Object../resources/assets/js/app.js (main.js?1598457867:10984)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js?1598457867:20)
    at Object.0 (main.js?1598457867:11011)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js?1598457867:20)
    at main.js?1598457867:84
    at main.js?1598457867:87
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright, so I did some searching and found the answer it was actually I was calling vue js the wrong way it actually
window.vue= require('vue');

Answer (score 1):

Try to chain the `mix` methods and before that, also run the `npm install` again, see the example given below.

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/main.js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/main.css')
    .version();
```